# Sliding overlay/lightbox/modal div effect

Tags: modal-dialog, lightbox, slide, effect

I am new to Jquery and I need to do something to the effect of the sliding content on this page: http://rocanov.com/

Is there an easy way to just make the div with the corresponding CSS and then just have it called to fly in from the left with Jquery when I click a link, like shown on that website?

A quick tutorial for this would be awesome. Can't find any on google. I don't really know how to describe it specifically.

**Solution down in the comments section of the checked reply**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two live examples, on *jsfiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/4KkFZ/ and on *codepen* http://codepen.io/paulalexandru/pen/iKGJl/
, i also posted all the code you need bellow.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<figure class="rift">
  <img src="image1.jpg" alt="image 1">
  <figcaption class="caption">Caption 01</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="rift">
  <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image 2">
  <figcaption class="caption">Caption 02</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="rift">
  <img src="image3.jpg" alt="image 3">
  <figcaption class="caption">Caption 03</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="rift">
  <img src="image4.jpg" alt="image 4">
  <figcaption class="caption">Caption 04</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
/* Base plugin styles */

.rift { 
  width: 300px; /* Define width */
  height: 200px; /* Define height */
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.rift img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
  opacity: 0;
}

.rift .caption { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Define caption height */
  line-height: 60px; /* Define matched line-height */ 
  margin: -30px 0 0 0; /* Half caption height */
  text-align: center; 
  z-index: 0;
}

.rift span[class*="span"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Acceleration FTW */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
  transition: transform .25s; /* Define anim. speed */
}

.rift span.top-span { top: 0; }
.rift span.btm-span { bottom: 0; }

.rift:hover span.top-span { 
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-30px);
  transform: translate(0,-30px); /* Half caption height */
}

.rift:hover > span.btm-span { 
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,30px);
  transform: translate(0,30px); /* Half caption height */
}

/* Non-plugin styles */

body { 
  text-align: center;
  background: #CCC; 
}

.rift { 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px; 
}

.rift .caption { 
  color: #FFF; 
  background: #C00C00;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
/**
 * Rift v1.0.0
 * An itsy bitsy image-splitting jQuery plugin
 * 
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * Copyright 2013 Kyle Foster @hkfoster
 */
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  $.fn.rift = function () {

    return this.each(function () {

      // Vurribles
      var element = $(this),
          elemImg = element.find('img'),
          imgSrc  = elemImg.attr('src');

      // We be chainin'  
      element
        .prepend('<span class="top-span"></span>')
        .append('<span class="btm-span"></span>')
        .find('span.top-span')
        .css('background', 'url(' + imgSrc + ') no-repeat center top')
        .css('background-size', '100%')
        .parent()
        .find('span.btm-span')
        .css('background', 'url(' + imgSrc + ') no-repeat center bottom')
        .css('background-size', '100%');
    });
  };
})( jQuery, window, document );

$('.rift').rift();
```

*Beside this, you need to load **jquery** and **normalize.css** also.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but the jsfiddle you posted does nothing but show the images. Mind explaining it?

Comment: You are right, it was working on Firefox but not on chrome because i forgot to put chrome css prefixes. (webkit-transition, etc). I've updated the answere and now it should work perfect.

Comment: Haha! Nice effect, but that's not exactly what I was pointing out. I was referring to the part when you **click on the images** and the div flies in from the left, not the hover effect. You seem to know what you are talking about so I hope you could also help in that part. Thanks for the replies man.

Comment: Ah. In that case you will need a slide panel effect. A 100% width panel witch shows from left to right. Something like this one http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/. Show/hide left slide menu with the speed increased. You have to set the background to transparent not to cover your top logo when the panel is showed and add the content you need in it. If you dont like that specific slide panel (witch is my favorite) just google "jquery slide panel".

Comment: Thanks Paul! Exactly what I was looking for! Love you man! No homo.

Comment: Haha I tried to rate it, but it says I still need 15 reputation or something. I'm new here, and I don't know what that means.

Comment: No need to press on that up arrow. You should press on the check mark beside the answer. If you do that, you will mark the answere as a good one and the question will be closed an you will gain reputation points. For more details about this check this url: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok, done. But can you help me a little with that Slide thing you posted? I can't seem to make it animate Slide. It just appears. I tried to copy the code as much as I could from the source, but it's not working and I've been trying to fix it for hours now.